# How can I prevent a pagebreak after an empty section?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I'm typesetting a roleplaying game rulebook in LaTeX. A frequently-occurring pattern in that problem space is a section header, followed immediately by a hierarchically lower section header—for instance, starting a section containing a list of items or traits, then going immediately into the first item. Consider the following source:

```
\section{Quirks}
\paragraph{External Docking Ports}
Rule text goes here.
```

Oftentimes, I find that produces output like this:

[image: demonstration]

The paragraph is pushed onto the next page, even though there's plenty of room for it on the preceding one. Sometimes, adding dummy text after the section heading will pull the lower heading up onto the preceding page (not in this one, though, because there isn't enough room).

Is there a way to inform LaTeX to very strongly prefer no page break in this case? I don't want them separated, but I don't mind if the higher-level heading gets pushed down, either. (I've been fixing them manually where the occur, so far—forcing a page break before the widowed section header.)

Ideally, though, I'd like some setting to tweak or command to use that makes that flow happen automatically.

Comment: This wouldn't happen with the standard setup. You probably have redefined `\section` or `\paragraph` (or both).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a small but complete, compilable document to your question that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: as others have said the standard section definitions would not page break there. But also note that you have skipped multiple heading levels, `\section` is level 1 and `\paragraph` is level 4 which will make a confusing table of contents layout if you increase the tocdepth

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that was the thing I needed to check—I haven't redefined them myself, but I am using `titlesec` and `needspace` on some lower-level headings, and that interaction was causing the unusual break.

@DavidCarlisle That's a good thing for me to keep in mind for future projects, but I'm sticking to section-and-up for the TOC on this project.

Comment: @Fishbreath it's still better logically to use `\subsection` rather than `\paragraph` (and then style subsections to look as you want)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The difficulty with that is that lists of items/skills/rules are always logically the lowest-level organization of the text, and occur under `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` at various points throughout.

Comment: @Fishbreath are you saying that real world requirements should win over logical purity? What a shocking idea:-)